# How to join tables in Oracle if I have a string with substrings in one table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, oracle11g

I have three tables with a difficult structure. I query them like this:

```
select sart.season, ost.art, ost.asize, sum(ost.kol) as sum_kol, gr.shopid
from firm.e_osttek_online ost
inner join firm.s_art sart on ost.art = sart.art
join firm.tdm_map_new_shop_group gr on 
(ost.id_shop = gr.shopid and
gr.season_out = case when gr.season_out != ' ' then sart.season end
)
where gr.s_group = '89901'
group by sart.season, gr.shopid, ost.art, ost.asize having sum(ost.kol) > 0 
order by ost.art, ost.asize;
```

The gr.season_out can contain spaces. it means that if there is a space don't use the join on the second condition as I specified in the case. It works well. Now the table  gr changed. The only change is that the season_out field may contain one season or a space or a string of a few seasons separated by a comma (before it was either one season or a space only). the sart.season can contain only one season and no spaces. How to rewrite the join now, retaining the space logic (it is crucial)? I know the structure is bad and I shouldn't put several seasons in one field of gr but I have no power over it, it is not my design. I merely have to query.

```
gr:
          SEASON                    S_GROUP           SHOPID  
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|         Winter           |        DescriptionW        |   A   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|    Winter, Allweather    |        Description2        |   B   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|
|                          |        DescriptionS        |   C   |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|-------|

sart:
          SEASON                    SOMETHINGELSE              ART
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|         Winter           |        SomethingElseW      |       1       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|         Allweather       |        SomethingElseA      |       2       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|
|            Fall          |        SomethingElseF      |       3       |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|---------------|

ost:
          ART                         ASIZE                     ID_SHOP     KOL
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         1                |        Stuff1              |          A       | 0  |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         2                |        Stuff2              |          B       | 20 |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
|         3                |        Stuff3              |          C       | 30 |
|--------------------------|----------------------------|------------------|----|
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Just wanted to show the more real query because "LIKE" from that thread is a good answer but doesn't take spaces into account. Without soaces would have been easier but I have to look out for them

Comment: I added the structure here with better names

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (if you really cannot interfere with the model and the inserted data) is to use the `INSTR` SQL function :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564

If `INSTR` return a non zero value then the searched string is found. In this case if INSTR return a non zero value then the value is match in the "composite key" thus even if you have spaces and/or comas.

The query should be something like this:

```
select sart.season, ost.art, ost.asize, sum(ost.kol) as sum_kol, gr.shopid
from firm.e_osttek_online ost
inner join firm.s_art sart on ost.art = sart.art
join firm.tdm_map_new_shop_group gr on 
(ost.id_shop = gr.shopid
and INSTR(gr.season_out, sart.season) <> 0
)
where gr.s_group = '89901'
group by sart.season, gr.shopid, ost.art, ost.asize having sum(ost.kol) > 0 
order by ost.art, ost.asize;
```